# Do I need Photoshop installed to use Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

Do I need to have Photoshop installed to work with Lightroom? Or is Lightroom totally independent of Photoshop? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Lightroom is an independent product with a different purpose.  Lightroom is a non-destructive digital darkroom product for making limited changes to images coming from a camera.  It is particularly good at working with RAW files and has built in RAW handling.  Since it is non-destructive, it does not save the image with changes applied, but rather saves a list of changes that need to be applied to an image.

While it supports integration with Photoshop (if you have Photoshop) so that you can do more advanced work either with the Lightroom image being used as a Smart Object, or by rasterizing (making the changes from Lightroom permanent on a copy) the image.  It is not necessary to have Photoshop unless you want to use that integration.

Lightroom is also perfectly capable of exporting the images with adjustments applied permanently as a final output from Lightroom.

Comment: Also you can setup Lightroom to easily open images in other Photoshop-like programs (e.g. GIMP) if you find yourself occasionally needing to do something that Lightroom can't and don't want to pay for Photoshop

Comment: In addition to what @StevenCunningham said, if you have not bought lightroom yet, look at getting the Adobe CC Photography pack. $10 a month for Lightroom and Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

Lightroom is totally independent. I have Lightroom 4 and do not have Photoshop.
I am happy. I need typical photo tweaks, fix a blemish, tweak saturation, etc. I dont need the power that Photoshop has.

Answer (score 3):

No,Lightroom totally independent of Photoshop.